# debug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart

when I run my App :: I receive this error : app: debugCompileClasspath

```
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

  ```
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  > Could not find cards.pay:paycardsrecognizer:1.0.0.
  ```

  Searched in the following locations:

  ```
  file:/C:/Users/Salhi/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/cards/pay/paycardsrecognizer/1.0.0/paycardsrecognizer-1.0.0.pom
  file:/C:/Users/Salhi/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/cards/pay/paycardsrecognizer/1.0.0/paycardsrecognizer-1.0.0.jar
  file:/C:/Users/Salhi/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/cards/pay/paycardsrecognizer/1.0.0/paycardsrecognizer-1.0.0.pom
  file:/C:/Users/Salhi/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/cards/pay/paycardsrecognizer/1.0.0/paycardsrecognizer-1.0.0.jar
  file:/C:/Users/Salhi/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/cards/pay/paycardsrecognizer/1.0.0/paycardsrecognizer-1.0.0.pom
  ```

Comment: Please explain more what you have done

Comment: Check Dart SDK is configured or not

Comment: Have you fixed that?